# HP EliteBook 850 G2 goes into bootloop after installing Ubuntu (both server and desktop)

Tags: boot, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an HP Elitebook 850G2.

I boot from USB and the installation appears to go flawlessly.

When the laptop boots after installation it goes into a boot loop.

I tried using both Server 20.04.3 and Desktop 21.10.

Laptop is on the latest HP BIOS.  These is not other OS installed on the computer.

What can I do to diagnose and resolve the issue.

Comment: Stay on the boot live media and try out the system as much as you can. Any errors?

Comment: I am able to use Ubuntu in "Try mode".  In fact I am replying to this on the ubuntu running in this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to replies from other sources I figured out that the problem was because Ubuntu was not able to determine the boot partition. The USB drive was formatted using both BIOS and EUFI and the HP BIOS was default Legacy. This

On the HP I set the BIOS to UEFI without CSM and formatted the USB drive using Rufus to also be based exclusively on UEFI (rather than support both BIOS or EUFI).

I reinstalled and it booted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to solve this and many problems which can cause this issue.

The very first thing you should try is check if the iso that you have downloaded is proper or not. To check that you can run a sha256 checksum on the iso file via

```
sha256sum path_file
```

and compare it to the checksum provided. Although this is generally a non issue since ubuntu runs a check before booting into live media but this is just to be safe.

Then you can boot into the live media and click on try ubuntu.
Then open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T and install boot-repair using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

then run the app via

```
sudo boot-repair
```

this should be able to fix most of the problems but If you are still unable to solve the issue Posting boot log files would indicate what the problem is. The boot log files are stored in **/var/log** which you can access by opening the file manager then on filesystems then on the drive you have on which Linux is installed and there var/log

Comment: I logged in using the "Try me" mode.  when I try to install boot-repair I am told:ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install boot-repair
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair

Comment: Is there are particular file I need to reference in /var/log?  From the "TryMe" mode I managed to find this directory on the original installation drive

Comment: chribonn, sorry about that now after I have edited the answer you should be able to do it. The directory /var/log is on filesystems in which your Linux is installed which can be accessed by the file manager (Nautilus) opening file systems and then your drive

Comment: Is there a way I can share the /var/log files?

I tried pasting in the bootstrap.log file but it exceeded the thread message length.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know much about that friend. I am afraid this is the current limit to my knowledge in this subject. You sure were not able to fix it via boot-repair ?

Comment: Thank you just the same, I apprecaite it.